# passing the parameters from adf to notebook

Tags: azure, foreach, parameters, azure-data-factory

Im ingesting a data with the api calls and would like to `widgets` to parametirze. In azure I have the following set up:
[image]

I have the list of `attribute_code`s, reading them with `lookup` activtiy and passing these parameter inside the databricks notebook code. Code inside the databricks:

```
data, response = get_data_url(url=f"https://p.cloud.com/api/rest/v1/attributes/{attribute_code}/options",access_token=access_token)
#Removing the folder in Data Lake
dbutils.fs.rm(f'/mnt/bronze/attribute_code/{day}',True)
#Creating the folder in the Data Lake
dbutils.fs.mkdirs(f'/mnt/bronze/attribute_code/{day}')

count = 0
#Putting the response inside of the Data Lake folder
dbutils.fs.put(f'/mnt/bronze/attribute_code/{day}/data_{count}.json', response.text)
```

My problem is that, since its in the `ForEach` loop, eveytime new parameter is passed, it deletes the entire folder with previosly, loaded data. Now someone can come and say to remove line where I drop and create the spacific daily folder but pipeline should run multiple times a day and I need to drop previously loaded data on that day and load new one.

My goal is to iterte over the entire list of the `attribute_code` and load them all in one folder with the name "data_{count}.json

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of using `dbutils.fs.rm` in your notebook, you can use delete activity before for each activity to get desired results.
- Using `dbutils.fs.rm`, the folder is being deleted each time the notebook is triggered inside for each loop deleting previously created files as well.
- So, using a delete activity only before for each loop to delete the folder (deletes only if it exists), you can load data as per requirement.

[image]

- For path, I have used the following dynamic content:

```
attribute/@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

[image]

- And using the following code in my databricks notebook:

```
#I used similar code
data, response = get_data_url(url=f"https://p.cloud.com/api/rest/v1/attributes/{attribute_code}/options",access_token=access_token)


#Creating the folder in the Data Lake
dbutils.fs.mkdirs(f'/mnt/bronze/attribute_code/{day}')

count = 0
#Putting the response inside of the Data Lake folder
dbutils.fs.put(f'/mnt/bronze/attribute_code/{day}/data_{count}.json', response.text)
```

- Lets say I have the following output from my look up activity:

[image]

- When I run the pipeline, it would run successfully. Only the latest look up data would be loaded.

[image]